# Node.js Kue how to restart failed jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, delayed-job, kue

I am using [kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue) for delayed jobs in my node.js application.

I have some problems to figure out how I can restart a job using the API of kue without having to move the id of a job manually from the the list of failed jobs to the list of inactive jobs using redis commands.

Is this possible using kue?

I don't want to set a fixed number of retry attempts - I just want to retry specific jobs.

Suggestions for a well maintained alternative to kue are also welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i dont know if this is working but you could try to reset the state of the job to active, and save the job again:

```
job.on('failed', function() {
  job.state('inactive').save();
```

Edit: setting state to inactive will correctly re-enqueue the task.

Comment: thanks! need to set it to "inactive" instead of "active" otherwise it won't get processed anymore. Had a look at the code and thought changing the state this way would not reassign the job to the given list.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done using queue level events.

```
queue.on('job failed', function(id, result) {
    kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job) {
        if (!err && shouldRetry(job))
            job.state('inactive').save();
    });
});
```

Thus you don't need to do for every job that you wish to retry. Instead you can filter it in the queue level event.

Answer (score 2):

**see Failure Attempts in the official docs**

> By default jobs only have one attempt, that is when they fail, they
>   are marked as a failure, and remain that way until you intervene.
>   However, Kue allows you to specify this, which is important for jobs
>   such as transferring an email, which upon failure, may usually retry
>   without issue. To do this invoke the .attempts() method with a number.

```
 queue.create('email', {
     title: 'welcome email for tj'
   , to: 'tj@learnboost.com'
   , template: 'welcome-email'
 }).priority('high').attempts(5).save();
```

reference: [failure attempts](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#failure-attempts)