# Job not restarting

Tags: javascript, node.js, kue

I setup a kue job as I usually do :

```
var job = jobs.create('phase2', s);
    job.on('complete', function (){
        console.log('Job'+job.id+' is done');
    }).on('failed', function (){
        console.log('Job'+job.id+'has failed');
    });
    job.save();
```

On certain conditions, I want the job to fail and restart automatically. For that, I have in my processor the following lines :

```
if(t==1){
    //Keep going
}else{
    console.log('PROBLEM');
    job.failed();
}
```

I have tried changing the failed event to :

```
.on('failed', function (){
    console.log('Job'+job.id+'has failed');
    job.state('inactive').save();
 });
```

as suggested here : [Node.js Kue how to restart failed jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280962/node-js-kue-how-to-restart-failed-jobs)

I have also tried adding attempts() as in the [Readme](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue#failure-attempts), like so :

```
var job = jobs.create('phase2', s).attempts(5);
```

None of these things have worked. The job is marked as 'failed' and my console shows 'PROBLEM', but I do not see the message defined in the 'failed' listener.

**EDIT**

After more reading, i've tried listening to the 'job failed' event at queue level, using :

```
  jobs.on('job failed', function(id,result){
    console.log('fail queue');
    kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job){
      job.state('inactive').save();
    });
  });
```

Same result, and no console log... It seem to be something else than Kue, any idea what could make the events not fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delayed jobs you need to add `jobs.promote()` to add the setInterval() that puts the delayed jobs back to the queue. Is also on the [README](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue#delayed-jobs). So you would need something like:

```
jobs.on('job failed', function(id, result){
  console.log('fail queue');
  kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job){
    job.state('inactive').save();
  });
});

jobs.promote();
```

At least that worked for my problem.